# StackApplet doesn't work in Linux Mint 17.1

Tags: linux-mint, software-installation, application

I installed `stackapplet` from the official repo, and the applet started fine, but I was not able to add my account using the preferences. When I try to add my username, nothing happens.

Even searching for my name is also not working. It seems like this is a problem which many people are facing but somehow there is no resolution to this problem. I even tried the latest version from Launchpad but that is also not working.

Moreover, the site list in the dropdown is also empty.

[image]

#### Reports of this problem:

- Launchpad bug report is [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/stackapplet/+bug/920770) but it has been put on low priority!!
- Users have reported the same problem on [Stackapps](https://stackapps.com/a/5054/33609) also.

It seems like this problem is resolved for many people. That is why it is not appearing so prominent on the various networks. However some people, including me, are still facing it.

So, the question is this : has anybody out there, got the `Stackapps` working on Linux Mint 17.1 or Ubuntu 14.04.1?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problems you describe, but managed to get `stackapplet` running on Ubuntu 14.04.

The trick was to manually create `stackapplet`'s configuration file, `~/.stackapplet/config`:

1. Stop `stackapplet`:

   ```
   killall stackapplet.py
   ```
2. Back up `~/.stackapplet/config`:

   ```
   cp -a ~/.stackapplet/config ~/.stackapplet/config.bak
   ```
3. Replace the contents of `~/.stackapplet/config` with:

   ```
   {"theme": "light", "accounts": [{"unread_reputation": 0, "last_comment_ts": 1433419194, "site_name": "Unix and Linux", "unread_comments": 0, "site": "unix.stackexchange", "reputation_on_last_poll": 313, "notifications": 0, "user_id": "26238", "last_answer_ts": 1433419196, "unread_answers": 0}], "language": "", "refresh_rate": 600000}
   ```

   Yes, **this is a long line of JSON data**. Don't prettify it, otherwise `applestack` will silently ignore `config` and overwrite it on exit with a default configuration file. Note that `config` doesn't have any end-of-line character, that is, there is no `\n` at the end of the JSON data string.

   Now locate and correct the value of the `user_id` key. Your user id is located on the top right corner of your profile page:

   [image]
4. Save the file and start `stackapplet`:

   ```
   nohup /usr/share/stackapplet/stackapplet.py &>/dev/null &
   ```

If you want to add more accounts, just add more elements to the `accounts` array. The trick here is to find out what `site` and `site_name` are for every 
StackExchange site:

- `site` is the site's URL with `.com` removed
- `site_name` is the site's "pretty name"

These are the sites I have currently configured in my `config` file:

```
 "site_name": "Ask Ubuntu"
 "site": "ubuntu.stackexchange"
 "site_name": "Unix and Linux"
 "site": "unix.stackexchange"
 "site_name": "Stack Overflow"
 "site": "stackoverflow"
 "site_name": "Server Fault"
 "site": "serverfault"
 "site_name": "Super User"
 "site": "superuser"
 "site_name": "Ask Different"
 "site": "apple.stackexchange"
 "site_name": "Ask Different Meta"
 "site": "meta.apple.stackexchange"
```

As reference, my `config` file is:

```
{"theme": "light", "accounts": [{"unread_reputation": 0, "last_comment_ts": 1433419181, "site_name": "Ask Ubuntu", "unread_comments": 0, "site": "ubuntu.stackexchange", "reputation_on_last_poll": 134, "notifications": 0, "user_id": "100272", "last_answer_ts": 1433419183, "unread_answers": 0}, {"unread_reputation": 0, "last_comment_ts": 1433419194, "site_name": "Unix and Linux", "unread_comments": 0, "site": "unix.stackexchange", "reputation_on_last_poll": 313, "notifications": 0, "user_id": "26238", "last_answer_ts": 1433419196, "unread_answers": 0}, {"unread_reputation": 0, "last_comment_ts": 1433419207, "site_name": "Stack Overflow", "unread_comments": 0, "site": "stackoverflow", "reputation_on_last_poll": 167, "notifications": 0, "user_id": "881191", "last_answer_ts": 1433419208, "unread_answers": 0}, {"unread_reputation": 0, "last_comment_ts": 1433419186, "site_name": "Server Fault", "unread_comments": 0, "site": "serverfault", "reputation_on_last_poll": 411, "notifications": 0, "user_id": "134501", "last_answer_ts": 1433419187, "unread_answers": 0}, {"unread_reputation": 0, "last_comment_ts": 1433419190, "site_name": "Super User", "unread_comments": 0, "site": "superuser", "reputation_on_last_poll": 3061, "notifications": 0, "user_id": "156041", "last_answer_ts": 1433419191, "unread_answers": 0}, {"unread_reputation": 0, "last_comment_ts": 1433419199, "site_name": "Ask Different", "unread_comments": 0, "site": "apple.stackexchange", "reputation_on_last_poll": 6681, "notifications": 0, "user_id": "32815", "last_answer_ts": 1433419202, "unread_answers": 0}, {"unread_reputation": 0, "last_comment_ts": 1433419200, "site_name": "Ask Different Meta", "unread_comments": 0, "site": "meta.apple.stackexchange", "reputation_on_last_poll": 6681, "notifications": 0, "user_id": "32815", "last_answer_ts": 1433419203, "unread_answers": 0}], "language": "", "refresh_rate": 600000}
```

Comment: Thanks for this interesting solution. However, this is not working for me. After manually editing the config file, I open the "preferences" and it still doesn't show any added account. And after exiting from `stackapplet` the config file is overwritten to its default.

Comment: However, your solution has been the best possible I've had so far on this issue. I'll keep trying.

Comment: @shivams If `config` keeps getting overwritten I suspect stackapplet is running. Could you please check with `ps -ef` that no stackapplet process is active and then edit the configuration file?

Comment: @shivams I've rewritten the answer to make it clear that `stackapplet` must be stopped before `config` can be edited. Could you please try it again and report?

Comment: I've checked there is no process running while editing the config files. Moreover, the files are not getting overwritten while Stackapplet is running. They are getting overwritten when it exits.

Comment: @shivams The culprit was that I prettified `stackapplet`'s configuration to make my answer more readable. As it turns out, `stackapplet` will ignore and overwrite a file formatted in pretty, human-readable JSON. Could you please revise my modified answer and report back?

Comment: You Sir, deserve a bounty :) This finally worked!! Thanks a ton :)

Comment: The account has got added. However there is one problem. In the drop-down of the applet, it is showing "Loading" continuously.

Comment: @shivams I'm glad the configuration loads correctly now. As for the "Loading" message, it seems there is some sort of network problem. It may be a proxy problem. If you use a proxy server to connect to the Internet follow the instructions in this document to configure the `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` environment variables: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-proxy-environment-variable/. Alternatively, you can set the `*_proxy` environment variables in a terminal session, run `/usr/share/stackapplet/stackapplet.py`, and test whether it works.

Comment: There is no proxy or anything. It's a direct internet connection. Anyways, somehow, it is working after I manually updated my reputation to my actual reputation in the config file. So, I guess, the issue seems resolved for now. But I'll just confirm if I am actually receiving any notifications or not.